# Simplest way to turn on a LED controlled from a 0v control signal?

Tags: led

Simplest way to turn on a LED controlled from a gnd or 0v signal and to turn the led off when voltage is added?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the simplest ways, assuming the input voltage is equal to (or a bit higher than) the voltage the LED operates from.

You could use a P-channel MOSFET and eliminate R1, which is slightly simpler, or use a single-gate logic chip which would be the same number of parts.

The input should be pulled to ground (not just left open) for the LED to illuminate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fak8y7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But the simplest way is simply to connect the LED + resistor between 5V and the input, if the input can drive it acceptably. That's only two parts. Or only one if you use a LED with built-in resistor.